# payment method is not visible after installing an extension

Tags: checkout, extensions, payment-methods

I installed extension in magento site.

after installing extension  i can not able to see the paymnet methods under checkout page.

```
app > code > local > extension_name > controllers > frontend > checkout > onepagecontroller.php
```

`onepagecontroller.php code`  = http://codepad.org/y4GVDLYL

check above code and help me what is the problem that why payment methods are not displaying?

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Comment: show rewrite code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baby in Magento 2,You have not rewrite controller properly.

Please study [here](http://www.amitbera.com/how-to-override-a-controller-in-magento/).

Config.xml rewrite code is:

```
<routers>
    <checkout>
    <args>
        <modules>
        <MyNameSpace_MyModule before="Mage_Checkout">Softprodigy_Bluedart_Frontend_Checkout</MyNameSpace_MyModule>
        </modules>
    </args>
    </checkout>
</routers>
</frontend>
```

Please donot use $_SESSION['avaiablePin'] .Use Magento session factory method

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session').
```

See how to set core session varible

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340982/how-do-i-save-value-in-my-own-session-variable-in-magento

http://joe-riggs.com/blog/2011/04/magento-session-variables/

Comment: i am in big trouble, i really need your help now.... is i have to add above config.xml code to our file?

Comment: that is what the code in extension? what i have to do now?

Comment: cannot understrand

Comment: http://codepad.org/PqgieAt1 config.xml from extension

Comment: i added your's above code to original config.xml code in site . see 155th line here: http://codepad.org/s2R4lRYA

Comment: do you want me to replace all "$_SESSION['avaiablePin']" to "Mage::getSingleton('core/session')." on onepagecontroller.php

Comment: Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setAvaiablePin($val); instead $_SESSION['avaiablePin']=$val for set val....

Comment: thanks, i did what you told , new onepagecontoller.php = http://codepad.org/WAYDcTCs , is i have to change "_SESSION['validpricelimit']" in file?

Comment: still payment method is not visible. is there anything else i have to do?

Comment: where config.xml code ?

Comment: this is the original config.xml code = http://codepad.org/s2R4lRYA

from 155th line, i added your code. please check the file and tell me what i am doing is right?

Comment: the above config.xml code was in app/etc/config.xml

but extension team gave another .xml file = > app/etc/modules/ Softprodigy_Bluedart.xml file = > http://codepad.org/PqgieAt1

Comment: you have doing wrong ... please study abount magento module stucture

Comment: can you please give your contact information either mail or skype, i want to send some code.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/users/4564/amit-bera